# Добавление пункта меню на сайт при установке собственного разрабатываемого модуля в систему "1С-Битрикс: Корпоративный портал"

Tags: битрикс

Учусь разрабатывать модуль для системы "1С-Битрикс: Корпоративный портал".

Во время установки модуля в систему возникла необходимость добавления пункта меню в корневое меню сайта, для добавления публичной части модуля на сайт (см. рисунок).

[image: Корневое меню сайта]

На данный момент пришёл к такому решению (все действия происходят во время установки модуля):

1. Определяю тип корневого меню сайта (для "1С-Битрикс: Корпоративный портал" по умолчанию это либо `left`, либо `top`) (с этим пока загвоздка, но как я понял нужно определить значение переменной `ROOT_MENU_TYPE`, которое передаётся в качестве параметра в вызов компонента `bitrix:menu`);
2. Из корня сайта беру файл `.[значение переменной ROOT_MENU_TYPE (left | top | ...)].menu.php`, считываю переменную `$aMenuLinks` из данного файла, хранящую массив ссылок, добавляю свою ссылку в переменную `$aMenuLinks`, после чего перезаписываю файл `.[значение переменной ROOT_MENU_TYPE (left | top | ...)].menu.php` с обновлённой переменной `$aMenuLinks`.

Скажите, пожалуйста, правильный ли это ход действий или предложите решение лучше.

(*) *Желательно, чтобы решение было на языке PHP, без использования JS*.

Comment: `.left.menu_ext.php` - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3254&LESSON_PATH=3913.4564.4949.4708.3254

Comment: @u_mulder

Я понимаю, что можно создавать меню динамически с помощью файла ".<тип меню>.menu_ext.php".

Но если придерживаться того решения, которое я описал в своём вопросе, то мне 1-ым делом нужно выяснить какой тип меню используется в корневой директории сайта (`ROOT_MENU_TYPE`).

Для добавления пункта меню нашёл следующий метод `WizardServices::AddMenuItem($menuFile, $menuItem, $siteID)` (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=101&LESSON_ID=3216&LESSON_PATH=8781.4793.3216).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задавал [данный вопрос службе поддержки Битрикс](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/support/customers/ticket.php?ID=2233355), где сказали, что способ, описанный в моём вопросе, вполне работоспособен.

В итоге сделаю инсталляцию модуля следующим образом:

1. (*по поводу 1-ого пункта из моего решения*) на первом шаге буду просить пользователя указать какой тип меню используется у него на сайте для 1-ого уровня (`ROOT_MENU_TYPE`) и какой для всех остальных уровней (`CHILD_MENU_TYPE`). Для получения информации о имеющихся типах меню в системе можно воспользоваться [функцией `GetMenuTypes()`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/33041/blog/1393/).
   В дальнейшем по возможности прикручу метод [`PHPParser::ParseScript`](http://bxapi.ru/src/?module_id=main&name=PHPParser%3A%3AParseScript), который посоветовала тех. поддержка Битрикс ([что метод `PHPParser::ParseScript` возвращает и как им пользоваться описано здесь](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/24164/blog/2026/));
2. (*по поводу 2-ого пункта из моего решения*) как я понял использовать методы класса `WizardServices` напрямую в модуле нельзя (например, [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/64466/), видно что завязываются на *Wizard* другого модуля и пишется что все эти действия необходимо производить в самом начале файла, т.е. вне [класса модуля равный ID модуля](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=101&CHAPTER_ID=04793&LESSON_PATH=8781.4793)). Покопавшись ещё в исходниках Битрикс обнаружил, что в модуле `crm` имеется метод `__AddMenuItem($menuFile, $menuItem,  $siteID, $pos = -1)`, который нигде не используется в файле установки `<DOCUMENT_ROOT>/bitrix/modules/crm/install/index.php`, но который использует функции модуля "*Управление структурой* (`fileman`)". И по этому решил перенести данный метод к себе в модуль, дополнив его методом для удаления пункта меню (`DeleteMenuItem`). В итоге получилось следующее:

```
function AddMenuItem($menuFile, $menuItem, $siteID, $pos = -1) {
    if (CModule::IncludeModule("fileman")) {
        $arResult = CFileMan::GetMenuArray(Application::getDocumentRoot().$menuFile);
        $arMenuItems = $arResult["aMenuLinks"];
        $menuTemplate = $arResult["sMenuTemplate"];

        $bFound = false;
        foreach($arMenuItems as $item) {
            if($item[1] == $menuItem[1]) {
                $bFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!$bFound) {
            if($pos < 0 || $pos >= count($arMenuItems)) 
                $arMenuItems[] = $menuItem;
            else {
                for($i = count($arMenuItems); $i > $pos; $i--)
                    $arMenuItems[$i] = $arMenuItems[$i - 1];

                $arMenuItems[$pos] = $menuItem;
            }

            CFileMan::SaveMenu(array($siteID, $menuFile), $arMenuItems, $menuTemplate);
        }
    }
}

function DeleteMenuItem($menuFile, $menuLink, $siteID) {
    if (CModule::IncludeModule("fileman")) {
        $arResult = CFileMan::GetMenuArray(Application::getDocumentRoot().$menuFile);
        $arMenuItems = $arResult["aMenuLinks"];
        $menuTemplate = $arResult["sMenuTemplate"];

        foreach($arMenuItems as $key => $item) {
            if($item[1] == $menuLink) unset($arMenuItems[$key]);
        }

        CFileMan::SaveMenu(array($siteID, $menuFile), $arMenuItems, $menuTemplate);
    }
}
```

---

Пример как вызывать данные методы (у меня они используются в методах `DoInstall` и `DoUninstall` в классе `abc_testmodule`):

```
class abc_testmodule extends CModule {
    const PUBLIC_DIR = "abc/testmodule/";
    const ROOT_MENU_TYPE = "top";

    ...

    function DoInstall() {
        ...
        // добавление пункта меню в публичной части
        $siteInfo = $this->getSiteInfo();
        $arMenuItem = array(GetMessage("ROOT_MENU_TITLE"), $siteInfo["DIR"].self::PUBLIC_DIR, array(), array(), "IsModuleInstalled('abc.testmodule')");
        $this->AddMenuItem($siteInfo["DIR"].".".self::ROOT_MENU_TYPE.".menu.php", $arMenuItem, $siteInfo["LID"]);
        ...
    }
    function DoUninstall() {
        ...
        // удаление пункта меню из публичной части
        $siteInfo = $this->getSiteInfo();
        $this->DeleteMenuItem($siteInfo["DIR"].".".self::ROOT_MENU_TYPE.".menu.php", $siteInfo["DIR"].self::PUBLIC_DIR, $siteInfo["LID"]);
        ...
    }
    // по заданию задано, что сайт будет всегда 1 (т.е. многосайтовость можно не поддерживать)
    function getSiteInfo() {
        $siteID = CSite::GetDefSite(); // s1
        return CSite::GetByID($siteID)->Fetch();
    }
}
```

---

(*) *В дальнейшем перенесу параметры `PUBLIC_DIR` и `ROOT_MENU_TYPE` в настройки модуля.*

Comment: Можно добавить универсальности 
    $menuFile = '/'.ltrim($menuFile, ' /');
    $menuFilePath = Application::getDocumentRoot().$menuFile;

Answer (score 1):

Есть два "легальных" метода:

**1.** Чтобы использовать метод WizardServices::AddMenuItem, нужно подключить соответствующие файлы:

```
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/wizard.php");
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/install/wizard_sol/utils.php");
WizardServices::AddMenuItem($menuFile, $menuItem, $siteID);
```

Сам метод реализован в файле /bitrix/modules/main/install/wizard_sol/utils.php но метода удаления пункта меню там нет. Поэтому его придется в любом случае реализовывать самому (чрез *CFileMan*), либо искать нужный метод во всех классах Битрикс через grep.

**2.** Для программного добавления пункта меню можно использовать событие *OnBuildGlobalMenu*. Регистрация обработчика при установке модуля производится с помощью метода - *RegisterModuleDependences*

```
// регистрируем обработчик события
RegisterModuleDependences("main", "OnBuildGlobalMenu", 
       "my_module_id", "MyClass", "OnBuildGlobalMenu");
```

не забудьте добавить *UnRegisterModuleDependences* в метод удаления модуля.

Проблема только в том, чтобы найти идентификатор необходимого меню. В большинстве примеров этот метод используется для **меню административной** части. Поэтому, способ редактирования файла меню (например через CFileMan, как это реализовано у Битрикс), остается самым актуальным.